# Retrieve catalog, metadata or schema information from MS Access database when connecting with PHP

Tags: php, database, ms-access

I am using following PHP code to connect to MS Access database:

```
$odb_conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$connstr = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=". $db_path.";";
$odb_conn->open($connstr);
```

How can I retrieve database catalog/metadata from the mdb file?

**FOUND THE SOLUTION**

```
$rs_meta = $odb_conn->OpenSchema(20, array(Null, Null, Null, "TABLE"));
```

Comment: You may be connecting to an MDB file created by Access, but via ADOB, all you have access to is the data tables, so you're really connecting to a JET database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find information on ADO here :

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675532(VS.85).aspx
- http://www.w3schools.com/ado/default.asp

The connection object has an OpenSchema method to get database schema information.

I don't know how to use MS Acces DB with PHP and how your new COM() object works, but I think it's better to use an OleDB connection instead an ADO object : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722784(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `MSysObjects` table can be used to query metadata in Access:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE Type In (1,4,6) AND Left([Name],4)<>"MSYS"
```

Comment: MSysObjects can often be inaccessible due to permissions issues that are a real pain to fix.