# Check access database if table exists

Tags: php, ms-access, adodb

Is there a way to check if table exists in mdb file? Im using PHP and ADOdb connection to connect.

here's my code

```
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$conn->open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; PWD=somepassword; DBQ=".dirname(__FILE__)."\filename.MDB;");
if (table exists){ \\ where i need the code to check
    $createtable = $conn->execute("CREATE TABLE $tblname (fieldsample CHAR(1))");
}else{
    $insertqry = $conn->execute("INSERT INTO $tblname (field) VALUES (value)");
}
```

Been browsing all day for the syntax but all I've seen so far are all for VB and ASP.

Comment: Horrible nasty work around, but off the top of my head can't you just try the `INSERT`, and create the table if it fails?

Comment: You could check the schema: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120114/retrieve-catalog-metadata-or-schema-information-from-ms-access-database-when-co

Answer (score 1):

What about a SELECT * on the table with LIMIT 1, and catch the error/exception?

(LIMIT is called TOP in ACCESS.)

So something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM <YOURTABLE>;
```

I learned to be practical when it comes to ACCESS, because it is barely a database.

Comment: True DaveRandom, I just discovered that myself. It is TOP. Fixed.

Comment: I agree... if it was me i would use sqlite coz i like it more but you really can't argue with old people, they're heads are hard as a rock.

Answer (score 1):

With COM available, you'd add a reference to DAO and check the [`TableDefs` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177479(v=office.12).aspx). Since you cannot do that, you'll have to resort to querying the hidden `MSysObjects` table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysObjects WHERE Name = 'myTable' AND Type = 1
```

(More details on this system table: [Using MSysObjects](http://www.perfectparadigm.com/tip001.html))

EDIT: According to this question, you can access the *schema data* using ADO, which should allow you to determine whether the table exists or not:

```
$rs_meta = $conn->OpenSchema(20, array(Null, Null, Null, "TABLE"));
```

- [Retrieve catalog, metadata or schema information from MS Access database when connecting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/120114/87698)

Comment: MSysObjects is an usupported feature and the table is frequently unavailable outside MS Access due to permission problems. The permissions can be a real problem to work around.

Answer (score 0):

```
$createtable = $conn->execute("CREATE TABLE $tblname (fieldsample CHAR(1))");
```

You could actually modify the query to achieve the results that you want:

```
$createtable = $conn->execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tblname (fieldsample CHAR(1))");
```

This query will be executed (create the table) if it's not there yet.  If its there already, this query will not be executed.

Comment: i guess it only works on database like mysql.  I guess I'll agree with DaveRandom, just execute an insert query, surround it with try-catch, if it fails, then create the table, if not then your query is executed.